# How to change the position or remove the default GPS icon of google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, google-api, fusedlocationproviderapi

I am new with google maps and its apis.Here i have loaded google map and trying to change the position of that GPS icon in attached image but its not getting moved from its position.

I have loaded map using **SupportMapFragment** and used **getMapAsync** method to get object of map in **onMapReady()** method.I know if i remove getMapAsync that icon will be removed but without it i can't get the object of map.So this is the issue i am facing.

Is there any to move position of it or remove it.
Help will be appreciated.Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to remove `Location Button` in onMapReady add

```
map = googleMap;
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thank you so much..that helped

Answer (score 1):

You can change this by getting the view of that current location button from Fragment

```
//Fragment code to change the position of the current location button
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
 mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        try {
            map = googleMap;

            if (mapFragment != null &&
                    mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")) != null) {
                // Get the button view
                View locationButton = ((View) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
                // and next place it, on bottom right (as Google Maps app)
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                        locationButton.getLayoutParams();
                // position on right bottom
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, 0);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, 0);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0);
                int marginBottom = mNavigationListFragment.llTypeContainer.getHeight() + 5;
                int marginRight = (int)convertFromDpToPixel(context, 10);
                layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, marginRight, marginBottom);
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


public static final float convertFromDpToPixel(Context context, float dp) {
        float ht_px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        return ht_px;
    }
```

To Hide that button use below code :

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    }
```